# In Skyrim, I married Iona, and said I want us to live at her house. Where is her house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just married Iona in Skyrim, and said we should live at her house. however, when I checked the map and quests, "show on map" is grayed out. Maybe she does not have a house? Is this a glitch? or, where is her house?

**More Info Update:** I was just two inn-lengths to the west of the Nightgate Inn, headed *away* from the inn, and the game popped up, "Completed: Visit your spouse's house". There are no houses in the vicinity that I could find, and I had already discovered the Nightgate Inn a long time ago. Additionally, the "Completed" message did not pop up when I was actually at the inn, but rather, when I was headed away from the inn about two inn-lengths west of the inn. I don't think her house is the Inn, but maybe I'm wrong? Don't know.

Why did the message pop up and did I find Iona's house? If so, where/what is her house? Thanks so much. p.s. I originally found Iona in my house in Riften, after I became Thane of Riften and she swore fielty to me.

Comment: I could be wrong, so I'm not going to post as an answer, but I *think* Iona's "house" is either the Keep in Riften, or your house. Which makes sense, since she's your housecarl upon becoming a Thane.

Comment: @desaivv Really?  It would seem very unlikely to me that you'd be allowed to "move in" to the Jarl's house - that is, unless there's just a single room in the Keep that you get.

Comment: @desaivv So, scratch the part in Tristan's comment about her "house" being the Keep?

Comment: I was about to add "hey, I found out where she lives". Then I just realized - that was only in my dream (real-life dream)! I dreamt that Iona had a house! So strange...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iona is a housecarl, and has no propriety of her own. "Her" house is your house in Riften, so you should find her there.

(and congrats on the wedding, best wishes, all that :) )

Answer (score 6):

She doesn't actually have her own house since she is a housecarl. Once you marry her you should find her at *your* house in Riften. For others that are unsure where that is here's a map. It's marked as number 7 (top left corner)

[image: Map of Riften]

If you still can't find her there you could look for her at the keep (33), thats the only other place I imagine she will be.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a second question:  What if you marry a housecarl, and don't own a house?  (Possible with Lydia, I believe, but probably not others.)

Comment: @Iszi Most of the cities require you to own a house to become Thane. I think maybe that any city which gives you a Housecarl, also requires you to buy a house to become Thane. So I don't think that could happen, to have a housecarl without owning a house.

Comment: @gameaddict That's why I said it would be possible only with Lydia - Whiterun is the only city I can think of that allows you to be Thane before you've purchased a house.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's already an answer, but what you answerers forgot is why the choice to visit spouses house was completed though he wasn't at the house. This is a glitch that is not known, but discovered by you due to the fact that Iona doesn't have a house, so then the choice completes itself because of that. You actually complete the option by going to your house in Riften, but this is a glitch that occurs not at someone's house.